# Creating JIRA search request excel view plugin and velocimacro to format output

Tags: macros, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I need to create a search request excel view plugin where the output is a list of issues under certain headings which are grouped by Issue Type. So far I have a plugin module project etc, so what I need help with is the velocity macro/template for such an output

As far as I can tell I need to create my own macro for issues, where I order the issues by accessing $issue.issueType.name and use this macro in issue-table-issue.vm

I am completely new to JIRA and plugin development so could anybody advise me about how to create a velocity macro for an excel layout in the form:

**Bug**

*table headings here*

issues here

**Task**

*table headings here*

issues here

etc...

Answer (score 0):

That is not easy at all. The default excel view does only one loop on issues. In you case, you should do a first loop per issue type to generate your header and then a second loop to render issues for the concerned type.

I invite you to look at the following JIRA sources:

1. `com.atlassian.jira.issue.views.SearchRequestPrintableView` as a start point to learn how you can replace Velocity rendering by your loop logic.
2. `com.atlassian.jira.issue.views.AbstractSearchRequestExcelView` to reuse issue rendering and apply your loop logic there, which should be more complex than in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

May be this book will be helpful to you: "JIRA 5.x Development Cookbook" by Jobin Kuruvilla

Excel reports described in Chapter 5.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the [Better Excel Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.betterexcel)** for this.

It can export search requests (in JIRA terminology) to Excel spreadsheets, while executing Groovy scripts! The scripts are typically used to pre-process the data, post-process that or to calculate some derived information that should also be exported.

In your use case, all you need to do is in the script:

1. You will get the exported issues as the variable *$issues*
2. Transform them to a issue-type to issue-list mapping (use a [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and a dead-simple Groovy transformer)
3. Return the map to Excel sheet

In the spreadsheet:

1. Iterate over the map using the [jt:foreach](http://www.midori-global.com/products/jira-better-excel-plugin/documentation/tags#h4) tag
2. Export the map key to a cell with a big bold font
3. Iterate over the map values using another *jt:foreach*
4. Export the current item (an issue) as usual

It saves you quite some efforts, but still leaves some coding to do (and you love coding, do you? :-)). 
The additional benefit is that the look is defined by Excel template spreadsheet, so the business users can easily change that (add some logo here, change fonts, etc.)